# What is the difference between Paris ham and French ham?

Tags: ham

My supermarket sells two kinds of pre-sliced ham. One is called Paris-style and the other French-style ham. Both kinds of ham are from the same company and the names are no indication of where the ham is made.

- Are these names widespread terms to used describe different types of ham?
- If so, what is the difference between how these are made?

Comment: A check of the ingredients might give you a clue. _Jambon de Paris_ is a specific type of lightly spiced ham. 'French style' ham sounds like marketing speak to me, because there is no one definitive French style of ham. You might as well say 'American-style hamburger'.

Comment: I agree with @ElendilTheTall that it is probably marketing speak. However, since is is the same brand, there most likely is a difference in the two products. Check the ingredients and method of preparation. Is it possible that one is Jambon de Paris (cooked) and the other is Jambon de Bayonne (dry cured)? Being that it is a style of ham, where it is produced would not be a factor. If all else fails, ask your grocer what the difference is. I would be interested to know what you find out! :)

Comment: I little digging into it shows that there's also a "Jambon de Paris Fumé", which is smoked.  I have no idea if that would show up on an ingredient list.

Comment: I have only been able to find one brand, A TABLE, (http://www.sinodis.com/en/brand/table) that appears to have both pre-sliced/packaged  French ham and Paris style ham. However, when I looked at each the descriptions were the same. Another suggestion might be for Village to contact the mfr. and ask for details.

Comment: Yes, that is the very brand. The packaging does not give much detail about the ingredients. Probably since they are a French-owned company that is why they add the word "French" to some of their products.

Answer (score 4):

Jambon de Paris (Paris Ham) is a slow cooked ham. The slow cooking means it retains a large percentage of its moisture and absorbs the flavours of the ingredients with which it is cooked.

Jambon de Bayonne is a dry cured or smoked ham that may or may not be further cured in red wine and given its name from the region in which it originates.

Both are sometimes identified as French Jambon ham. French-style ham would probably indicate the use of one or both methods to produce the final result. But as Elendilthetall mentioned it is just marketing speak for an imitation.

Answer (score 1):

French ham is slowly cooked in just-simmering water and is seasoned only with salt.  It is made with high-quality pigs and is hoped to be very juicy, almost wet.  It is the preferred type of ham for ham and butter baguette sandwiches, a French staple.

Answer (score 0):

A French ham is like a Boston ham. Cut from the shoulder. Packed tight in a cask. Then shipped. on ships for food for sailors or to America as food for troops in the civil war. Not the best of ham but good enough for those type of people. It packed well in cask in the 1800s Did not need refrigeration. Also known as Nausue ham or pork. Shipped all the way from Nausue France to feed the troops. Paris ham was good enough to keep in France for food. You could always tell French ham by the special greenish color.